# Outlook after compacted ost size is different from online server data size

Tags: outlook

guys.

I had compacted the ost file which only contains one mail, it shows 11G large, but in outlook mailbox cleanup setting -> view mailbox size -> server data, it only shows 8.5G large, So which one is right?

Luke

Answer (score 0):

They both are right. The size of the local OST file can be and is different from the size of the online mailbox. The properties are stored in a different way, Exchange uses attachment single instancing, etc.